# Selenium python webscraper - How to select only the first document in a webpage list that changes?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

So, I have most of this webscraper written, but the one thing I don't know how to do is select the top/first pdf document in a list of documents from this website https://tofino.civicweb.net/filepro/documents/855?expanded=100967. New pdfs are supposed to be added to the top of the respective year's folder monthly. Normally I would select the document by xpath and download it that way, but I don't know if this will work in this situation. Does the question make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the first PDF just use:

```
driver.FindElementsByClassName("document-link")[0].click()
```

If you want to now download that, try:

```
driver.FindElementById("ClicktoDownLoadnotice").click()
```

*ClicktoDownLoadnotice is the id of the PDF preview button*

Finally, download the PDF:

```
driver.FindElementById("maskedImage").click()
```

*"maskedImage" is the ID of the download button if you are on Chrome*